# Open Flash Chart on Zend MVC Error

Tags: model-view-controller, open-flash-chart

I recently downloaded the Open Flash Chart source code and I have intergrated it into my Zend MVC.Since I use the autoloader
I have renamed my files and commented the "require_once" source lines.

However when I try to load my chart

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        "<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/swf/open-flash-chart.swf", 
        "my_chart", "550", "200",
        "9.0.0", 
        "<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/swf/expressInstall.swf",
        {"data-file":"<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/reportexpense/piechart/"}
    );
    </script>
```

it loads the `"/data-files/y-axis-auto-steps.txt"` instead and I cant figure out why.

My controller returns the JSON string which I expect to be rendered.
What am I missing?

Comment: running into this same problem right now!  haven't figured it out yet

Comment: actually I did figure out my problem.Let me post the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to help out those who might come across the same problem.
I adjusted my code to read

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

 swfobject.embedSWF(
            "<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/swf/open-flash-chart.swf", 
            "my_chart", "550", "200",
            "9.0.0", 
            "<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/swf/expressInstall.swf",
            {"get-data":"get_data_1"}
        );

 function ofc_ready()
 {
     //alert('ofc_ready');       
 }

 function get_data_1()
 {      
     return JSON.stringify(<?php echo $this->myreport?>);        
 }

</script>
```

It worked perfectly.

Comment: @davykiash- Simply awesome for your sharing mate!!


I was really looking for something that will read the data from view variable instead of reading JSON from a file to make it properly integrate with zend and your code modification simple works for me.

   
I did some last minutes silly mistake."my_chart" is a id not class.Hope this can be useful for someone.

Thanks. 
kazi tanvir ahsan(ktanvirahsan)